# Python dictionary in a dictionary printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm trying to print the value of 'a' in couples in random_dict but the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" is coming up,

Code:

```
coupleascore = 20
couplebscore = 23
couplecscore = 25

judge1scores = [1, 3, 5]
judge2scores = [5, 2, 10]
judge3scores = [7, 5, 9]

random_dic = {'couples': {'a': coupleascore, 'b': couplebscore, 'c': couplecscore} ,'judges': {'1': judge1scores, '2': judge2scores, '3': judge3scores}}

print(key(['random_dic'['couples'['a']]]))
```

Comment: `print(key(['random_dic'['couples'['a']]]))` should be `print(random_dic['couples']['a'])`

Comment: Thank you very much, I would like to ask another question but ill have to wait another 90 mins for that, please may I ask you it here?

Comment: @TIC-FLY If my answer solved your original question, could you please mark it as resolved? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your last line to this:

```
print(random_dic['couples']['a'])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries for more on the dictionary data structure

Comment: Thank you for your time to help me.